# JMeter: Aggregate report analysis

Tags: jmeter

I want to test the capacity of the web app that can handle without break.how to get the average requests per second from the aggregate report.

Is throughput is equal to average requests per second ?

I don't really need Apache definition.please make it simple.

Number of threads : 25
ramp-up :1
Loop:10

I have 3 slaves.
samples:250
Avg:1594
Throughput:10.4

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains the answer: `Throughput:10.4`

According to [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> **Throughput** is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
>
> The formula is: Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).

So my assumption is that you generate the load of 10 requests per second (it may be per minute however, I need to know how long did your 250 samples execute to tell for sure)

If you're interested in "requests per second over time" you can utilize [Server Hits Per Second](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) listener which is available via JMeter Plugins project.

Alternative option of visualizing your load test results is using [Loadosophia.org](http://loadosophia.org/) cloud where you can upload your test result and see graphs, distributions, export load test report as PDF, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I think there is no need to get success for every server hits.right ? Then for a software testing can we depend server hits/second ?

Comment: Tset duration is 10 seconds.total samples 250.